# Facebook iOS app embedded browser debug tools?

Tags: ios, facebook

My website (not an app), allows people to stream audio while clicking around to other pages on the site (ajax and hashtags).  So the site url might be m.mysite.com and when you click on a link for m.mysite.com/#mobile/3 you get a news story.  This used to work fine in the iOS Facebook app's browser.  Since the latest update, we get site header and footer but none of the actual content.  Is there a tool for debugging this?